# Calculating CPU Utiliization for Round Robin Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, cpu-usage, round-robin

I have been stuck on this for the past day. Im not sure how to calculate cpu utilization percentage for processes using round robin algorithm.

Let say we have these datas with time quantum of 1. Job Letter followed by arrival and burst time. How would i go about calculating the cpu utilization? I believe the formula is

total burst time / (total burst time + idle time). I know idle time means when the cpu are not busy but not sure how to really calculate it the processes. If anyone can walk me through it, it is greatly appreciated

```
A 2 6
B 3 1
C 5 9
D 6 7
E 7 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Well,The formula is correct but in order to know the total-time you need to know the idle-time of CPU and you know when your CPU becomes idle? During the **context-swtich** it becomes idlt and it depends on short-term-scheduler how much time it take to assign the next proccess to CPU.

In 10-100 milliseconds of time quantua , context swtich time is arround 10 microseconds which is very small factor , now you can guess the context-switch time with time quantum of 1 millisecond. It will be ignoreable but it also results in too many context-switches.

Comment: i see if i were to code this for round robin, What part in the code should i do this ?

Comment: @liang123 i do not understand you